# DB SQL Performance Measurement Values for JMeter

Tags: database, performance, jmeter

I have a question regarding DB Performance. Are there any standard measures / repsonse times for DBs?

E.g. A Oracle DB with this Configuration (..) takes 20ms to query a record out of 1 million entries.

Or is it more a individual comparison for each DB Environment?

Answer (score 0):

Such "standards" are simply not possible as there are too many factors which matter and the data and its setup in the database will always be different.

Given you are doing load testing you should have **performance requirements** from business level so check your project non-functional requirements for this information. If it is missing - the only thing you can do is measuring current performance, collecting the metrics and if you possess enough expertise - detecting "heavy" SQL queries and suggest improvements (build-in and 3rd-party tools can be used for this, i.e. [explain query plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan), [sql query analyzer](http://www.quackit.com/sql_server/tutorial/sql_query_analyzer.cfm), [precise i3](http://www.precise.com/sitecore/content/precise/home/databaseone/database-one))

With JMeter alone you will be able to [create a database test plan](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter) and if you have some expected response times to use [Duration Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Duration_Assertion) to fail the samplers if response time exceeds defined threshold

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for the quick reply. As u mentioned i don't have requirements on business level (besides of "it's slow ;-))

My plan was do create some test cases / a test plan and then run this several times to see if some performance improvements which were done are having a postive impact

Just another question: is it possible to say that a sql query (e.g select from ...) needs twice the time if twice the data are stored in the db table (ignoring all other impacts)

Comment: Unlikely. More data - longer query execution time, but the factor might be different